# Прием сообщений

Tags: сеть

Жутко интересен алгоритм работы приема информации от http сервера до клиента на любой платформе. Не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому и не знаю, как найти на этот вопрос ответ в интернете (уверен, что в интернете есть ответы). Чтоб было понятно, хороший пример - диалоги вконтакте. Вот каким образом приходит сообщение от сервера до браузера? Бесконечная проверка на наличие новой информации? Мне кажется, что это неправильно. Тогда как? Буду благодарен за ответ, а если не сложно - пожалуйста, прикрепите простейший пример такого алгоритма на любом языке. Заранее спасибо

Comment: В случае с ВК - да, там именно бесконечная проверка, хотя это конечно не очень оптимально

Answer (score 2):

Это называется постоянное соединение из HTTP.  На примере вконтакте - это называется WebSocket, с помощью которого можно передавать данные через постоянное соединение. Здесь есть вполне хорошее описание принципа работы вебсокетов - https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

Comment: спасибо огромное)

Comment: Вконтакте не использует вебсокеты

Comment: да, вк используют long pooling, работает примерно отсылает запрос -> ждёт ответа в течении 20-30 сек -> перезапускает соединение и дальше ждёт ответ. но WebSocket по сути более новая технология